# Speed up the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator Task Group in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I have followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd) and I am using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator task group in an Azure DevOps pipeline to successfully run my integration tests.

[image: See here for how my pipeline is setup]

The problem comes when on each run it takes approximately 20 mins to download the emulator. This means with multiple pushes to a branch plus a merge build it can take up a lot of time/resource.

Does anybody know if/how it would be possible to speed this up? I suppose what I actually want to do is cache the emulator image that the task group is downloading each time. However it always seems to pull latest.

Comment: Are you on a Microsoft hosted agent or on a self-hosted agent? I'm guessing the former. Caching a big docker image is ideally something you do on a self-hosted agent that can store the image on disk locally. Since the hosted agent always starts with a clean slate, no matter what you do, you'll end up having to download the emulator from somewhere.

Comment: I've been seeing this same problem on Microsoft hosted agents from time to time for a few years now, so I think there would be value in answers that address that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The latest provided windows-images should come with the CosmosDB emulator pre-installed on the device. See [the docs](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#database-tools) on pre-installed software for a list of what's available.